# Using fct_relevel over a list of variables using map_at

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tidyverse

I have a bunch of factor variables that have the same levels, and I want them all reordered similarly using `fct_relevel` from the `forcats` package. Many of the variable names start with the same characters ("Q11A" to "Q11X", "Q12A" to "Q12X", "Q13A" to "Q13X", etc.). I wanted to use the `starts_with` function from `dplyr` to shorten the task. The following error didn't give me an error, but it didn't do anything either. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(forcats)
library(tibble)

#Setting up dataframe
f1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f2 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f3 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f4 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f5 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df <- tibble(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)

levels(df$f1)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

#Attempting to move level "c" up before "a" and "b".
df <- map_at(df, starts_with("f"), fct_relevel, "c")

levels(df$f1)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" #Didn't work

#If I just re-level for one variable:
fct_relevel(df$f1, "c")
[1] a b c d
Levels: c a b d
#That worked.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for `mutate_at`:

```
df <- mutate_at(df, starts_with("f"), fct_relevel, ... = "c")

df$f1
```

> ```
> [1] a b c d
> Levels: c a b d
> ```

Comment: Evidently I'm confused as to when I should use `purrr::map` and when I should use `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: That's easily forgiven. You usually want to use the different `mutate` variations for columns,  and `map` within `mutate` for list columns and unvectorized calculations.

Comment: @akrun, sorry I'm only finding decent dupes that end up using `mutate_each`, which is planned to be deprecated. Feel free to hammer if you have a good `mutate_at` target.

Comment: It's okay.  You may be right that it is difficult to find those with `mutate_at`