# How to use fct_relevel with mutate_at syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I want to relevel the factors in a dataset, however I'm really struggling with the fct_relevel syntax and using it with mutate_at. I get a series of errors about my data not being a factor.

The solution must allow me to relevel multiple factors (the actual dataset has 20-odd factors to relevel in different ways)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859468/using-fct-relevel-over-a-list-of-variables-using-map-at) seems like it should work, but I'm clearly not picking up the syntax properly. Where am I going wrong?

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble (x1 = c("b", "b", "a", "c", "b"),
               x2 = c("c", "b", "c", "a", "a"),
               y = c(10, 5, 12, 3, 4)) %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(x1:x2), factor)
```

I'm definitely dealing with factors

```
sapply(dat, class)
```

But I can't relevel x1, I receive the following error: `f must be a factor (or character vector))`

```
dat %>% fct_relevel(x1, "c", "b", "a")
```

And this is what I ideally want to be able to do

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars (x1:x2),
            .funs = fct_relevel("c", "b", "a"))
```

At the moment that final set is giving me the following errors:

Error: Can't create call to non-callable object

Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

In addition: Warning message:

Unknown levels in f: b, a

I'd be really grateful for anyone pointing out what I'm sure is an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
library(dplyr)                     
library(forcats)

dat <- dat %>% mutate_at(vars(x1:x2), ~fct_relevel(., c("c", "b", "a")))

dat$x1
#[1] b b a c b
#Levels: c b a
dat$x2
#[1] c b c a a
#Levels: c b a
```

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks so much - I knew it would end up being simple.