# Updating fct_relevel solution since across took over mutate_at

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr, forcats, across

The solution to [piping fct_relevel to mutate a subset of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036568/how-to-use-fct-relevel-with-mutate-at-syntax) no longer works since mutate_at has been deprecated. I'm having a tough time piecing together an updated solution using `mutate(across(...), fct_relevel(., ....)` , since I get an error that

```
"Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
i `..2 = ~...`.
x `..2` must be a vector, not a `formula` object."
```

but there is no formula

Let's say I have

```
f1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
g2 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
t3 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f5 <- factor(c("m", "l", "f", "p"))
y8 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df <- tibble(f1, g2, t3, f5, y8)
```

and I want to `fct_relevel` f1, g2, and y8 (so non-sequential variables) so that you have the factors ordered as "c", "d", "b", "a" for all three of these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this:

```r
library(dplyr) # 1.0.7
library(forcats) # 0.5.1

f1 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
g2 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
t3 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
f5 <- factor(c("m", "l", "f", "p"))
y8 <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df <- tibble(f1, g2, t3, f5, y8)


df_1 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(f1, g2, y8), forcats::fct_relevel, "c", "d", "b", "a"))

levels(df$f1)
#> [1] "c" "d" "b" "a"
levels(df$g2)
#> [1] "c" "d" "b" "a"
levels(df$t3)
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
levels(df$f5)
#> [1] "f" "l" "m" "p"
levels(df$y8)
#> [1] "c" "d" "b" "a"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Below I add two more syntaxes that are equivalent to the one above.

```r
# option 2
df_2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(f1, g2, y8), ~forcats::fct_relevel(., "c", "d", "b", "a")))

# option 3
df_3 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c(f1, g2, y8), ~forcats::fct_relevel(.x, "c", "d", "b", "a")))

identical(df_1, df_2) # TRUE 
identical(df_1, df_3) # TRUE
```

The way the above `fct_relevel()` operates is that it treats each column (i.e., `f1`, `g2`, `y8`) as a vector passed to `fct_relevel`, plugged in instead of the `.` or `.x`. It "knows" to do such "plugging" because we use the `~` right before the function.

Comment: Yes, I see, it wasn't working because I was assuming the structure needed to be fct_relevel("c", "d", "b", "a"). Can someone chime in with why it isn't declared in the usual function format?

Comment: @ibm, see my added section. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I think I was probably closing c() after the variables were declared, and that's why when I tried options 2 and 3 on my own I was getting an error about the formula formatting. Thanks for putting these alternatives together.